# Ward, k-means, and another method?

Tags: clustering

I conducted both Ward and k-means clustering. The main results were the same, but some results were different, affecting the cluster's interpretation. In such cases, it would be better to report both results, but if I perform another method, and if its result is the same as the result of Ward or k-means, then either interpretation could be robust. Would you please let me know if there is any recommended third method, perhaps from recently developed methods? I would like to use methods other than traditional methods such as simple, average, complete, etc.

Comment: If you want to optimise the k-means objective function (which is what both k-means and Ward do), you should use the solution that gives you the better objective function value, which usually is k-means (depending on the algorithm you use; Hartigan-Wong trying out lots of different initialisations should pretty much always beat Ward). If you want to go for something different, there are about 500 further methods, if not more. Generally the choice of method depends on what exactly your data are, aim of clustering etc.   https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.02059

Comment: @Lewian: Thank you. If you post your information as an answer, not a comment, I will accept it as the best answer. Do you happen to know if I can get an objective function value in using NbClust R package? I guess it's not easy unless I make changes to its codes (I do not want to do that.) My results from k-means and Ward were almost the same. Would it be an acceptable practice just to report both results to show the robustness of clustering and not to choose one algorithm? I really appreciate your comments.

Comment: I don't know more about NbClust than what's in the documentation. Ward and k-means supposedly optimise the same objective function, so the fact that they agree or about agree doesn't prove the "robustness" of the clustering, as this is expected anyway. It is surely not wrong to present both solutions, however it really doesn't add much insight to showing just one of them. (If you want to optimise the objective function, most likely k-means - better focus on improving that by trying out enough initialisations -; if you want a hierarchy then Ward.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Tom M., my earlier comment posted as answer:

If you want to optimise the k-means objective function (which is what both k-means and Ward do), you should use the solution that gives you the better objective function value, which usually is k-means (depending on the algorithm you use; Hartigan-Wong trying out lots of different initialisations should pretty much always beat Ward). If you want to go for something different, there are lots of further methods (and I mean *lots*, as in *hundreds*, no joke). Generally the choice of method depends on what exactly your data are, aim of clustering etc., see
https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.02059

Regarding Ward vs. k-means, if you want to optimise the objective function, most likely k-means is better - better focus on improving that by trying out enough initialisations -; if you want a hierarchy for some reason, then Ward.  It is surely not wrong to present both solutions, however it really doesn't add much insight to showing just one of them, because  Ward and k-means supposedly optimise the same objective function, so the fact that they agree or about agree is to be expected anyway, and  doesn't prove the "robustness" of the clustering.

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful comment. I really appreciate it. Because there are many sources providing misleading information on this point, your answer will be helpful for other scholars.